# Does moving to EF 4 need to target .net 4?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a .net 3.5SP1 project with EF (1 i guess). How the upgrade to EF4 occurs ? I need to target .net 4 ?
Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

You will need .Net4.0 for EF4.

Comment: And Visual Studio 2010 also :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - .Net 4.0 is needed.